# How do I gsub an empty "" string in R?

Tags: r, gsub

How do I replace an empty string?

This:

```
x = c("","b")
gsub("","taco",x)
```

produces:

```
"taco"      "tacobtaco"
```

instead of:

```
"taco"      "b"
```

Is there any way to replace an empty string?

Comment: You could also do `x[x == ""] <- "taco"` and avoid regexes altogether.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use `nchar` here:

```
 x[nchar(x)==0] <- "taco"
```

**EDIT**

If you are looking for performance so you should use nzchar:

```
x[!nzchar(x)] <- "taco"
```

Comment: Is this faster than Konrad's solution or why do you recommend it?

Comment: @Roland personally I find more it elegant than character comparison and add another option for better performance.

Comment: @agstudy when i try this, i seem to get everything replaced with taco. after resetting R, it seems to work. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
x = c("","b")
gsub("^$","taco",x)
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t use `gsub` here – semantically, I think of `gsub` as replacing parts *within* a string. For replacing a whole string, I would just use subsetting. And since you’re searching for a fixed string (`''`), it doesn’t even need regular expressions:

```
x[x == ''] = 'taco'
```

(Of course this reassigns the original vector `x`, whereas `gsub` just returns the modified result.)