# R+Arrow 10.0: Bug when Using gsub?

Tags: r, linux, apache-arrow

A bit of a follow up question of

[R+arrow: Error when using the dataset API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159537/rarrow-error-when-using-the-dataset-api)

Please have a look at the reprex at the end of the post.
Essentially, I work on a data file without loading it into memory and I want to replace "" with "0" in a string.

In order to do so, I use the expression at

[How do I gsub an empty "" string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565118/how-do-i-gsub-an-empty-string-in-r/22565209#22565209)

which works when I use it on a standard tibble, but not
inside an arrow pipeline followed by collect().
I believe this did not happen with arrow 9.0.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp

ll <- c(      "1000000",   "10000000",  "2000000"  , "30000000" , "500000"   ,
        "5000000", ""   ,   "Not Range")


df <- tibble(x=rep(ll, 1000), y=seq(8000))




write_tsv(df, "data.tsv")

data <- open_dataset("data.tsv", format="tsv",
                     skip_rows=1,
                     schema=schema(x=string(),
                     y=double())
)

test <- data |>
    collect()

###I want to replace the "" with "0". I believe this worked with arrow 9.0

df2 <- data |>
    mutate(x=gsub("^$","0",x) ) |>
    collect()


df2 ### now I did not modify the  "" entries in x
#> # A tibble: 8,000 × 2
#>    x               y
#>    <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 "1000000"       1
#>  2 "10000000"      2
#>  3 "2000000"       3
#>  4 "30000000"      4
#>  5 "500000"        5
#>  6 "5000000"       6
#>  7 ""              7
#>  8 "Not Range"     8
#>  9 "1000000"       9
#> 10 "10000000"     10
#> # … with 7,990 more rows




df3 <- df |>
    mutate(x=gsub("^$","0",x) )

df3  ## and this is fine
#> # A tibble: 8,000 × 2
#>    x             y
#>    <chr>     <int>
#>  1 1000000       1
#>  2 10000000      2
#>  3 2000000       3
#>  4 30000000      4
#>  5 500000        5
#>  6 5000000       6
#>  7 0             7
#>  8 Not Range     8
#>  9 1000000       9
#> 10 10000000     10
#> # … with 7,990 more rows

## How to fix this...I believe this issue did not arise with arrow 9.0.

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] arrow_10.0.0    forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.4.1   dplyr_1.0.10   
#>  [5] purrr_0.3.5     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8   
#>  [9] ggplot2_3.3.6   tidyverse_1.3.2
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] lubridate_1.8.0     assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.30      
#>  [4] utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0   
#>  [7] backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2        evaluate_0.17      
#> [10] httr_1.4.4          highr_0.9           pillar_1.8.1       
#> [13] rlang_1.0.6         googlesheets4_1.0.1 readxl_1.4.1       
#> [16] R.utils_2.12.1      R.oo_1.25.0         rmarkdown_2.17     
#> [19] styler_1.8.0        googledrive_2.0.0   bit_4.0.4          
#> [22] munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.1         compiler_4.2.1     
#> [25] modelr_0.1.9        xfun_0.34           pkgconfig_2.0.3    
#> [28] htmltools_0.5.3     tidyselect_1.2.0    fansi_1.0.3        
#> [31] crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.3.0          dbplyr_2.2.1       
#> [34] withr_2.5.0         R.methodsS3_1.8.2   grid_4.2.1         
#> [37] jsonlite_1.8.3      gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3    
#> [40] DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3      scales_1.2.1       
#> [43] vroom_1.6.0         cli_3.4.1           stringi_1.7.8      
#> [46] fs_1.5.2            xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2     
#> [49] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.5.0         tools_4.2.1        
#> [52] bit64_4.0.5         R.cache_0.16.0      glue_1.6.2         
#> [55] hms_1.1.2           parallel_4.2.1      fastmap_1.1.0      
#> [58] yaml_2.3.6          colorspace_2.0-3    gargle_1.2.1       
#> [61] rvest_1.0.3         knitr_1.40          haven_2.5.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: FYI, this works correctly (replaces `""` with `"0"`) with arrow-9.0.0 on win11, R-4.1.2.

Comment: ... and I can confirm that it is a problem (win11, R-4.1.2) in arrow-10.0.0, so this is a regression in arrow. I suggest you submit a [bug report](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues), as I can't find an open issue with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug. I filed a bug report here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-18202 .

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `if_else()` or `case_when()`, which is probably faster anyway `data |> mutate(x = if_else(x == "", "0", x)) |> collect()`

Comment: Correct. There are workarounds, but in any case a bug is a bug and this needs to be fixed essentially because you do not get an error message, but gsub "simply" does not do what it is supposed to.